# Using launchd to activate daemon on file owner change

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, launchd

I'm trying to get a "daemon" (really just a script, more than a background process) to activate when a file (specifically, `/dev/console`) changes owner (i.e., when another user takes control of the console) on MacOS Mojave.

I'm trying to do this by running launchd and having it watch that file for changes. I tried doing this with WatchPaths, as in the script below, but apparently that only notices "creating, removing and writing to this file", not chown. Script is below, along with more background story. Any ideas on how to do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>LoginScripts.blockyoutube.sh</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/Shared/blockyoutube.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/dev/console</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/var/log/blockyoutube.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/var/log/blockyoutube.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

---

**Backstory**

What I'm really trying to do is block my kids' accounts from YouTube ... but not my wife's account on the same computer. In theory System Preferences->Parental Controls should do this fine — which it does ... until someone launches Chrome and it backchannels the DNS lookup to 8.8.8.8.

The only way I've figured out to work around this is to not let the OS DNS query fail, so Chrome doesn't attempt to do that, so I'm updating /etc/hosts to point to localhost and flushing DNS whenever the console owner changes. Other solutions to this backstory are also welcome, but it does seem that there should be a way to make `launchd` watch for change in owner of a file.